# How to throw exception as converting a string to an int array in Java?

Tags: java

1.Expected output:

The input is a string, the expected output is an int array.

For examples:

(1) input: a string, such as "1234";

```
=> output: int array: {1,2,3,4}
```

(2) input: "12s4"

```
=> output: throw out an Exception.
```

2.My code:
I'm converting the input string to an int array as the following:

```
int[] StringToArray(String strInput) {

    int[] nArray = new int[strInput.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<strInput.length(); i++) {
        nArray[i] = Character.digit(strInput.charAt(i), 10);
    }

    return nArray;
}
```

But when the input is a character, the output can still be converted to an integer.
For example, "12s4" is converted to be [1,2,-1,4].

3.Question:

How can it throw out an Exception if there is a character such as 's' in the input string？

Thank you.

Comment: Consider using [isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))

Comment: Are you having problems with throwing an Exception or with checking if it is not a digit?

Comment: Although `char` isint a number as such it is an integer (I think) and it is signed, unlike the other integer types, I think this is due to it representing the unicode characters that formed the original ASCII character set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `String#matches` here to assert that no character be a non digit:

```java
int[] StringToArray(String strInput) throws Exception {
    if (!strInput.matches("\\d+")) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid input contains non digits");
    }

    int[] nArray = new int[strInput.length()];
    for (int i=0; i < strInput.length(); i++) {
        nArray[i] = Character.digit(strInput.charAt(i), 10);
    }

    return nArray;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `! strInput.matches("\\d+")` be better? No backtracking, and clearer intent.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it would be better, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do that is to check if the value returned from `Character.digit()` is -1 or not and then throw an exception.

```
int[] StringToArray(String strInput) {

    int[] nArray = new int[strInput.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<strInput.length(); i++) {
        nArray[i] = Character.digit(strInput.charAt(i), 10);
        if(nArray[i] == -1){
            throw new Exception("Invalid input - contains non digit: " + strInput.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return nArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if (Character.isLetter(nArray[i])) and throw a exception

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `Character.isDigit()` to test input `char` for digit.

```
public static int[] StringToArray(String strInput) {
    int[] res = new int[strInput.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(strInput.charAt(i)))
            res[i] = strInput.charAt(i) - '0';
        else
            throw new NumberFormatException();
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `split("")` to get a `String[]` and then cast it to a `int[]` using `Integer.parseInt()` which throws a `NumberFormatException` like

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int[] x = stringToArray("1234");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        try {
            int[] x = stringToArray("1234");
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public static int[] stringToArray(String strInput) throws NumberFormatException {
        int[] nArray = new int[strInput.length()];
        // Cast String to List<Integer>
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.stream(strInput.split("")).map(character -> {
            // Do not handle cast exception
            return Integer.parseInt(character); // Does raise NFE
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // Cast List<Integer> to int[]
        for(int i=0; i<strInput.length(); i++) {
            nArray[i] = numbers.get(i);
        }

        return nArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] toArr(String s) {
        String[] digits = s.split("");
        int[] arr = new int[digits.length];
       for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
           arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(digits[i]);
       }
       return arr;
   }
```

java.lang.NumberFormatException will be trown if you put something but digits in your string